# Header problems in TChromium

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded

I´m having some problems using an embedded Chromium instance in a Delphi legacy application.

At first I thought I was having some kind of cookie trouble as I couldn´t see any cookie in the Developer Tools. Instead I was seeing a warning with the text: "Provisional headers are shown".

I saw this error report in the CEF project:
http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=14422
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2136/devtools-network-inspector-provisional

And it seems the problem is still there.

Is there any way to do some workaround to this?

Comment: From what I remember, there's no way to refresh developer tools from the interface (you can show and hide dev. tools, but not refresh for the current site request). Can you build CEF from source? I could try to check what's wrong..

Comment: Oh, I have no trouble with the dev tools, my problem is that Chromium is removing headers, such as the cookies so the server is not aware of my (already) open session.